# How to use ::after pseudo for Font Awesome instead of ::before pseudo

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

Font Awesome is not providing `:after` pseudo. Is it possible to use `:after` by default instead of `:before` pseudo?

For Example if I use: `<i class="fa fa-facebook">facebook</i>` then icon should use `:after` instead of `:before`.

I don't want to use an icon as per below:

```
<span> 25 <i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span>
```

if I use above solution then it's definitely work. I can put icon after 25 but I am not in situation to use this

In my case :

```
<span class="percent fa fa-percent">25</span>
```

current result:

```
.fa-percent:before {
    content: "\f295";
}
```

expected result:

```
.fa-percent:after {
    content: "\f295";
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```css
.percent:after {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: "\f295";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="percent">25</span>
```

Comment: it's one solution but I want to alter ::before by ::after without override fontawesome content is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of.